# Read http response with Content-Type : multipart/x-mixed-replace, Javascript

Tags: javascript, streaming, multipart

**[SOLVED] readable streams**

Chunks (byte[]) are written (an nothing else) directly to the response outputStream , on client side this code inside an async function reads that response's chunks nicely as they arrive as uInt8Array

```js
const response = await fetch(url);
const reader = response.body.getReader();

while (true) {
  const { value, done } = await reader.read();
  if (done) break;
  console.log('Received', value);
}

console.log('Response fully received');
```

Code read at https://web.dev/fetch-upload-streaming/

**[OLD]**

I would like to do the same implementation as `<img src="stream/video.mjpeg">` does when that url returns a response with contentType:  multipart/x-mixed-replace. Somehow the browser reads "chucks" from an unfinished/on-going response.

Why? I want to stream .h264 format, with jMuxer ([/example/h264.html](https://github.com/samirkumardas/jmuxer/blob/master/example/h264.html)), here WebSocket are used, but "feels wrong" because sockets are for bidirectional communication (I suposse this is true).

So, the response which  `<img>` consumes succesfully and it is generated in server side(Java) looks like:

```
for(int[] bytes: listWithFrames){
                    responseOs.write((
                                "--BoundaryString\r\n" +
                                "Content-type: image/jpeg\r\n" +
                                "Content-Length: " +bytes.length +
                                "\r\n\r\n").getBytes());
                    responseOs.write(bytes);
                    responseOs.write("\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
                    responseOs.flush();}
```

First I've tried writting just `bytes` on the response ussing `XMLHttpRequest` like [XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data), but `oReq.response` is set when response ends and `oReq.responseText` is not null only when `oReq.responseType = "text";`

Encoding in Base64 each `bytes` to make it visible on `oReq.responseText` and then decoding it can't be also the way because it adds a lot of size and `oReq.responseText` grows forever (could be avoided by doing multiple request and a buffer to keep feeding jMuxer)

Do I really need Node? [making-http-request-and-receiving-multipart-x-mixed-replace-response-in-node-js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60224571/13771772) I am looking for some kind of `fetch` that give me access to each recived binary (arraybuffer/uInt8array) part as they arrive.